# List sorting in python - AAA vs AA etc

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am struggling with sorting a list into an order that is useful for my business case, I have been using the sorted() function.

My list looks like this when using the sorted function:

```
['A', 'AA', 'AA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'C', 'CC', 'CCC', 'D']
```

However I need the list to output the following:

```
['AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA','AA', 'AA','A','CCC','CC', 'C', 'D']
```

AAA is higher than AA but A is higher than CCC etc. Can this be accomplished using out of the box functionality or has anyone got a solution they can offer?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Is every string guaranteed to consist of the same letter?

Comment: How about `AB` vs `A`?

Comment: What's the rule exactly? Can it be expressed in English?

Comment: Are this 'AAA' -> D credit ratings?

Comment: These seem to be not just strings, but actual representations of *something*. Consider to create a class or even enum with well-defined ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = ['A', 'AA', 'AA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'C', 'CC', 'CCC', 'D']

sorted(a, key=lambda x: (x[0], -len(x)))
>>>>['AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AA', 'AA', 'A', 'CCC', 'CC', 'C', 'D']
```